# How to select one item of array in Mongodb?

Tags: jquery, database, mongodb

The data model is something like this:

```
"_id":...
"special_offers": [ 0 => Object, 1 => Object, ...]
```

I just need to get `0 => Object`, I mean, the first item of the `special_offers` array.

Here is what I've tried:

[image]

But as you can see, all items of the array are visible in the result. Any idea how can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array:

```
{ special_offers: { $slice: 1 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `_id` value of the first element then you can do:

```js
db.collection.find({
   special_offers: {
      $elemMatch: {
         _id: ObjectId('6349770ba47302dd542518fa')
      }
   }
},{ 'special_offers.$':1 }
);
```

Or if you only know the `_id` of the parent document then you can do:

```js
db.collection.find({_id: ObjectId('650ecb0f507561a33ce927aa')},
{ 
   special_offers: {
      $first: "$special_offers"
   }
});
```